# How to assign the option value from a dropdown to select id of another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have a long select dropdown menu. On click on each option another dropdown should display. This is a sample html code. So, when I select section1,  selction will appear with section1 id and when i click on section2, section2 dropdwon will be displayed.

```
<select id="section_id" name="section">
<option>--Select -</option>
<option value="section1">section1</option>
<option value="section2">section2</option>
</select>

<select id="section1" name="sub_section">
<option>--Select -</option>
<option value="section1">subsection</option>
<option>subsection</option>
</select>
<select id="section2" name="sub_section1">
<option>--Select -</option>
<option value="section1">section</option>
<option>section</option>
</select>


My js code:

$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#section_id").change(function(){
            var v = $(this).val();
            var y = document.getElementById(var);
             if (if (v==y)){
                $("#" + y).show();
             }
             else{
                $("#" + y).hide();
             }
            });
        });
```

Comment: var is not a defined variable. You mean `v`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#section_id").change(function(){
             var v = $(this).val();
             var y = $('#'+v);
             y.show();
             y.siblings('[sub_*]').hide()
            });
        });
```